# Is it possible to recreate the deploy bytecode of a contract in solidity?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

So I'd need something like the `GetCode.at(address)` function presented in the official doc: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/assembly.html#example
but which allows me to deploy that contract in a new address.
Is it possible to get the deploy bytecode or rebuild it from the runtime one with solidity?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw bytecode and try to redeploy with a new transaction. Set the "data" part of the transaction to the existing bytecode and submit. You can submit using MetaMask (if you're using web3) or even using the geth console. Lots of articles out there on how to do that.

I'm guessing you have the source code or the ABI somewhere? Otherwise, you won't be able to call the contract's functions.

Comment: hey thanks, but I need to do it in solidity. I guess is not possible.

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/holiman/069de8d056a531575d2b786df3345665.

Basically, it uses assembly to copy the bytes at a specific address. You would need to know the constructor args and the address of the original.

Answer (score 1):

The `.getCode()` method only returns you the deployed bytecode. What you want is the `data` that was sent alongside the transaction that deployed the contract. Etherscan gives you a link to the deploying transaction.

For instance, for [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x10d4b24938f6de7ae4048c7273f09c50d5caf4d9), the deployment took place [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6ee10781280ccbcb38644e63cb4ba1f50360b60ce606ca089c2c05e065865592). So that's the bytecode that will deploy a new contract.

Keep in mind that the longer bytecode also contains the constructor parameters towards the end. So if you want to deploy by hand, don't forget to update those too.

Comment: Hey thanks, I know, but as I said, I need to do it in solidity. I guess is not possible.

Comment: There is a way in `assembly {` to get the deployed code of a contract. To deploy it at another address, you would have to prepend it with the constructor and append it with the constructor arguments. So in effect you need some prior knowledge of how this specific other contract was deployed.